# Returning C# functional extension's Result when reading from database

Tags: c#, .net-core, csharpfunctionalextensions

I've inherited a dotNet Core project that heavily uses the [C# Functional extensions nuget package](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions), and especially its Result class. This goes as far as returning a Result when retrieving records from the database. I see methods looking like

```
public async Task<Result<IEnumerable<MyEntity>>> GetAll(CancellationToken token)
{
    var variableForDebugging = await _dbContext.MyEntity.ToListAsync(token);
    return await _dbContext.MyEntity.ToListAsync(token);
}
```

This snippet is a fair representation of the real code, I have only changed the name of the entity, but have not omitted any try-catch clauses. I have two questions with respect to the code snippet above:

(1) Does it make sense to return a Result when reading records from the database? If I deliberately ensure that the application cannot connect to the database, I get an exception and not a `Result.Failure`, and I cannot think of a scenario in which the code snippet would return a Failure result.

(2) When I check the type of the result handed to me by EF, e.g. upon inspecting the type of `variableForDebugging`, it is of type `List<MyEntity>`. However, the return type of the method is `Task<Result<IEnumerable<MyEntity>>>`, so how does the compiler figure out that it can wrap `List<MyEntity>` in a Result and return `Task<Result<IEnumerable<MyEntity>>>`?

Comment: The answer to 2 is `public static implicit operator Result<T>(T value)`; a `List<MyEntity>` is implicitly convertible to `Result<IEnumerable<MyEntity>>` by chaining the implicit (standard) conversion from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and the implicit user-defined conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `Result<IEnumerable<T>>` (the `Task` wrapping is part of the `async` mechanism and not a conversion as such). The bit in the standard that covers conversion rules is also the most complicated, so don't ask me to follow this process through the formal steps.

Comment: The answer to 1 is, I think, subjective; if you like things like `Result` in the first place, there's no real reason not to use it for consistency, and then you probably should not be letting an exception escape in the first place, but catch it and convert it to a failure. In this case you've got a bit of a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" situation in that code bases that expect to use things like `Result` would expect a method that does *not* return `Result` to never fail, and this method can clearly fail (in a way that you probably don't want to be a hard crash).